# how to get usable data between -1 and 1 from QAudioBuffer? Qt6

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I would like to know how to efficiently extract data from a QAudioBuffer object. I have a wav audio file that I am decoding with a QAudioDecoder object. I want to extract the results of the decoding contained in the QAudioBuffer object to apply filtering operations on it and finally send the filtered data to a subclass of QIODevice to listen to the result in real time.

At first, I just do a test to make sure that the extraction works well. To do this, I save the data contained in the QAudioBuffer object in a txt file. But I encounter 2 problems.

- the resulting TXT file contains only characters, no numbers.
- With MATLAB, when I plot the signal represented by the data contained in the TXT file, I get the   shape of the original audio signal (the one in the WAV file) but the amplitudes are too big and should be between -1 and 1.

Can you please tell me how to extract the data so that I get a result on which I can apply a filter and how to have data between -1 and 1?

I use Qt6.4

thanks in advance

the code and the slot

```
QAudioFormat *format_decoder;
format_decoder = new QAudioFormat;
format_decoder->setSampleRate(44100);
format_decoder->setChannelCount(1);
format_decoder->setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int16);

QAudioDecoder decoder;
decoder.setSource(filenameSource);
decoder.setAudioFormat(*format_decoder);
decoder.start();

QObject::connect(&decoder, &QAudioDecoder::bufferReady, this, &MainWindow::test_copy_to_txt)
```

the slot

```
void MainWindow::test_copy_to_txt(){

    QAudioBuffer audioBuffer = decoder.read();
    const qint16* samples = audioBuffer.constData<qint16>();  // Signal shape ok, but not the amplitudes

    QFile outputFile(filenameTest1);
    if(!outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append)){
        qDebug() << "ERROR";}

    QTextStream out(&outputFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < audioBuffer.sampleCount(); ++i) {
        out << samples[i] << "\n";   // only characters, no numbers.
    }
    outputFile.close();
}
```

another question: Can you recommend a documentation other than the one on the Qt site to have more details on audio processing with Qt? How do the classes react to each other? An example so that you understand why I am looking for such documentation is the pure virtual function quint64 readData(char *data, quint64 Len) from QIODevice. For my project, I will have to reimplement it, but I would like to know what function calls it and how to determine the Len parameter.

Comment: Your sample format is 16-bit integer, so each sample can range from -32768 to 32767, but more likely +/- 32767. The usual way to convert that to floating-point is to divide each sample by `32767.0f`. On a separate note, writing the raw bits out to a _text file_ is a bad idea. Files opened in text mode will translate certain bytes. For instance, `\n` in Windows results in `\r\n` (CRLF). If this happens to you, your data stream will be completely broken. Open the file in _binary_ mode if you're writing binary data.

Comment: To ensure your value doesn't for some reason get treated as a character (guessing that Qt might possibly treat `qint16` as a UTF-16 value), then just cast it: `out << (int)samples[i] << "\n";` Or do the floating-point output: `out << samples[i] / 32767.0f << "\n";`

Comment: Side note: If you're storing binary, store the 16 bit value and convert it to floating point when read back. This'll chop the file size at least 50%. File reading is slow, so you can probably read the 16-bit ints and do all of the divisions in less time than it would take to read the floating point file. It's surprising how much simple compression can actually SPEED UP file processing .

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I followed your recommendations and everything is ok now.Here is the corrected code
 `out << static_cast< float >(samples[i]) / std::numeric_limits<qint16>::max() << "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I followed your recommendations and everything is ok now.
Here is the corrected code

```
out << static_cast< float >(samples[i]) / std::numeric_limits<qint16>::max() << "\r\n";
```